# How do I send a call to php from swift

Tags: swift

I’m trying to send a simple update from Swift(UI) to a php server but running into a fatal error when trying to work with the return data and I can’t see what the issue is.
What am I missing / doing wrong here?

The Webservice code:

```
func siteFavourite(siteID: String, userID: String, updateType: String, completion: @escaping (Result<Bool, NetworkError>) -> Void){
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.overseer.cyou/explorer/siteFavourite.php") else {
        completion(.failure(.invalidURL))
        return
    }
    let body = siteUpdateBody(userID: userID, siteID: siteID, updateType: updateType)
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpBody = try? JSONEncoder().encode(body)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let updateData = data, error == nil else {
            completion(.failure(.noData))
            return
        }
        let response = try! JSONDecoder().decode(updateResponse.self, from: updateData)
        let status = response.status
        if status == 1 {
            completion(.success(true))
        } else {
            completion(.failure(.noData))
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Called from a regular button -

```
(siteID: String(site.id), userID: "2", updateType: "favouriteAdd") { result in
                        switch result{
                        case .success(_):
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                print("Site \(site.id) toggled")
                                withAnimation {
                                    siteData.sites[siteIndex].isFavourite.toggle()
                                }
                            }
                        case .failure(_):
                            print("Site \(siteIndex) failed to toggle")
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Never do try! When decoding external data

Comment: There should be an error in console. I guess it's because of the `try!`. Why did you write `try!`? You could have written `do { try ... } catch { }`, or `try?` or `try!`, so why choose `try!`? What's the benefits of each ones? Downsides?